# How to clone the SharePoint list attachment field in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2013

How to clone attachment Field in Access 2013? It gives me an "Invalid argument" error, with the FileData field.

FileData shows in the debugger as type Variant/Byte. And looks like an array of bytes.

I am using a standard SharePoint list style attachment field.

Examples I have seen [Copy An Attachment Field](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/copy-attachment-field-t2002857.html) suggest the following code will work, but I get an error of "Invalid argument"

```
Public Sub copyAttachment(recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom As DAO.Recordset2, recordsetMoveAttachmentTo As DAO.Recordset2)

      Do While recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom.EOF = False
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo.AddNew
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo!FileFlags = recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom!FileFlags
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo!FileName = recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom!FileName
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo!FileTimeStamp = recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom!FileTimeStamp
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo!FileType = recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom!FileType
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo!FileURL = recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom!FileURL
        recordsetMoveAttachmentTo!FileData = recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom!FileData            recordsetMoveAttachmentTo.Update
        recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom.MoveNext
      Loop

      Set recordsetMoveAttachmentFrom = Nothing 'Clear the Record set
      Set recordsetMoveAttachmentTo = Nothing 'Clear the Record set

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

- **.Update** the parent record.
- copy FileData field using:

  ```
    lngOffset  = 0
    conChunkSize = fldSource.FieldSize
    chunk = fldSource.GetChunk(lngOffset, conChunkSize)
    fldDestination.AppendChunk chunk
  ```

It is not possible to save the attachment record until the parent record has been saved. Also to copy the fileData field use GetChunk and AppendChunk

*Warning* - AppendChunk only worked with the first append. After that all appends failed.

While MS provide the below example (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220958(v=office.12).aspx) AppendChunk does not look to work correctly with Access 2013

```
   ' Set size of chunk in bytes.
   Const conChunkSize = 5& * 1024 * 1024

   Dim lngOffset As Long
   Dim lngTotalSize As Long
   Dim chunk As Variant

   ' Copy the photo from one Recordset to the other in 32K
   ' chunks until the entire field is copied.
   lngTotalSize = fldSource.FieldSize
   Do While lngOffset < lngTotalSize
      chunk = fldSource.GetChunk(lngOffset, conChunkSize)
      fldDestination.AppendChunk chunk
      lngOffset = lngOffset + conChunkSize
   Loop
```